# "Has no supported translation to SQL" after extracted method from linq statement

Tags: c#, linq

I have this linq statement:

```
 public IEnumerable<EventModel> GetList(
     EnumEventCategory? category = null,
     EnumEventType? type = null)
 {
      var listDB = from e in this.DataContext.Event
          join i in this.DataContext.Identifier on e.ID equals i.ID
          orderby e.Deadline, e.ID descending
          select new EventModel
          {
           ID = i.ID,
           IdentifierStatus = i.IdentifierStatus,
           IdentifierType = i.IdentifierType,
           EventCategory = e.EventCategory,
           EventType = e.EventType,
          };

      if (category != null && category != EnumEventCategory.Unknown)
      {
        listDB = listDB.Where(x => x.EventCategory == category);
      }

      if (type != null && type != EnumEventType.Unknown)
      {
        listDB = listDB.Where(x => x.EventType == type);
      }

      return listDB;
 }
```

When I extract a method from that code, it is throwing exception 

`Method 'BrandNewDay.OENO.Lib.Models.EventModel EventModel(BrandNewDay.OENO.Data.Identifier, BrandNewDay.OENO.Data.Event)' has no supported translation to SQL.`

```
 public IEnumerable<EventModel> GetList(
     EnumEventCategory? category = null,
     EnumEventType? type = null)
 {
     var listDB = from e in this.DataContext.Event
                  join i in this.DataContext.Identifier on e.ID equals i.ID
                  orderby e.Deadline, e.ID descending
                  select EventModel(i, e);

      if (category != null && category != EnumEventCategory.Unknown)
      {
          listDB = listDB.Where(x => x.EventCategory == category);
      }

      if (type != null && type != EnumEventType.Unknown)
      {
          listDB = listDB.Where(x => x.EventType == type);
      }
      return listDB;
 }

private static EventModel EventModel(Identifier i, Event e)
{
    return new EventModel
    {
        ID = i.ID,
        IdentifierStatus = i.IdentifierStatus,
        IdentifierType = i.IdentifierType,
        EventCategory = e.EventCategory,
        EventType = e.EventType,
     };
 }
```

any ideas?

Comment: (re-written after closer inspection) Nope, that won't work, you have to `select new`. Add that method as a ctor to the EventModel class and it will start working.

Comment: Thanks Alex. I tried that, but it didnt work.